# Strategy for making bets but only being able to get money after placing at least $\alpha$ bets.

Tags: probability, game-theory, gambling

Suppose that we are at a casino, we have $m$ money, we can place bets of any size $x$ and win with probability $p<0.5$ (if we win we get $2x$ money) , but we need to place bets which add up to at least $\alpha$ dollars in order to withdraw our money.

What is the expected amount of money we can win if we play optimally? Call this $F(m,\alpha)$.

Clearly we have $F(m,0)=m$ and we have $F(m,\alpha)=\max\limits_{0< x \leq \alpha,m}(pF(m+x,\alpha-x)+(1-p)F(m-x,\alpha-x))$, so we get a nice recursion for $F$ over $\alpha$.

Does a closed form exist? I think that the recursion 
$F(m,\alpha)=pF(m+\min(\alpha,m),\alpha-\min(\alpha,m))+(1-p)F(m-\min(\alpha,m),\alpha-\min(\alpha,m)))$ is true but I haven't been able to prove it.

Is this problem famous?

Comment: What is the payoff for winning?

Comment: You get to withdraw whatever you have, but you need to satisfy the condition.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  If you win a single bet, how much do you win (whether you can withdraw it or not)?

Comment: Oh, you get whatever it is that you bet, the cash gets doubled.

Comment: If that's the case, the optimal strategy is to do 1 bet of size  $\alpha/2$ (or, even better, zero bets, that is, not play).  This is how it always is with bets with a negative expected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the total amount of money we bet (in one or more rounds) is $\alpha'$, then the expected loss from these bets is $(1-2p)\alpha'$. Thus for $\alpha\le m$, the optimal strategy is to bet a total of $\alpha$ (in a single bet or with several bets, it doesn't matter) and then withdraw an amount $m'$ with expected value  $$E[m']=m-(1-2p)\alpha\qquad(\alpha\le m)$$

Things get more complicated if $\alpha>m$. 
We need to reach the winning zone even to withdraw! 
We will certainly stop as soon as the total bets add up to $\alpha$ (as any further betting produces expected loss), but we may be broke before that after having bet only $\alpha'<\alpha$. By this, the *expected* value $E[\alpha']$ of total bet amount may be smaller than $\alpha$. At any rate, we still have $E[m']=m-(1-2p)E[\alpha']$.
This tells us that we want to minimize $E[\alpha']$.
In other words, try to be broke as quick as possible if you fail to win.
This reminds us of [*"How to gamble if you must"*](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiA95Lj1dTTAhVDQBQKHRCsAWMQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.maa.org%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fpdf%2Fjoma%2FVolume8%2FSiegrist%2FRedBlack.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFWBm2glnLbqT5IUsi4tdemOKcDbw&sig2=Wuv5hJCBClD55DwEgStcKQ) and the recommendation to use **bold play**, i.e., in each round bet as much as we need to reach a preselected target amount $m'$ at once if possible, or otherwise bet all we have.

Adapted to our situation: As long as the remaining $\alpha$ is greater than $m$, bet all you have. If we lose, we win nothing, otherwise start the same considerations with $\alpha$ replaced by $\alpha-m$ and $m$ replaced by $2m$.

If we denote $F(\alpha,m)$ as the value of $E[m']$ for the given $\alpha$ and $m$, we thus obtain the recursive functional equation
$$ F(\alpha,m)=\begin{cases}m-(1-2p)\alpha&\text{if }\alpha\le m,\\
pF(\alpha-m,2m)&\text{if }\alpha\ge m.\end{cases}$$
Clearly (and as we might have guessed), $F$ is homogeneous. To simplify, we define $f(x):=\frac1mF((x-1)m,m)$ (so that $F(\alpha,m)= mf(\frac\alpha m+1)$) and see that this obeys
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}1-(1-2p)(x-1)&\text{if }1\le x< 2,\\
2pf(\frac x2)&\text{if }x\ge2.\end{cases}$$
Thus for $2^k\le x< 2^{k+1}$, we take the lower branch of the recursion $k$ times and then the top branch.
Summarized in one single closed formula, we arrive at
 $$f(2^ku)=(2p)^k(1-(1-2p)(u-1))\qquad\text{if }1\le u<2$$
or at
$$f(x)=(2p)^{\lfloor \log_2 x\rfloor } \bigl(1-(1-2p)(2^{-\lfloor \log_2x\rfloor }x-1)\bigr).$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very nice. Initially I made the mistake of assuming $\alpha' = \alpha$ and I got a wrong answer, this makes a lot of sense.